# Can we get AWS EC2 status 1/2 or 2/2 status in terraform output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Can we get AWS EC2 status 1/2 or 2/2 status in terraform output ? and can we run terraform destroy via cron ?

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Did you manage to add external resource?

Comment: @marcin how can i use aws cli commands in python script  ?As i am new to python and terraform like aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id i-0f8d06b73782a9020

Comment: @marcin I have made a new question .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66882605/boto3-script-to-get-instance-status-1-2-or-2-2-in-terraform-using-external-data .Could you please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data source [aws_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance) does not provide such information. Thus, you could create **custom data source** by means of [external](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source).

The custom/external data source would call **your own program or script** that would query the EC2 instance status, e.g. using [describe-instance-status](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html) and return to TF for further use.

And yes, you can run TF through cron.