# Boto3 script to get Instance Status 1/2 or 2/2 in terraform using external data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Can you help me for Boto3 script to get Instance Status 1/2 or 2/2 check in terraform using external data source .I am new to python and Terraform .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bash as shown in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source#processing-json-in-shell-scripts) could be easier

**get_instance_status.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(.id)"')"

status=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --output json --query 'InstanceStatuses[0]')

instance_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.InstanceStatus.Details[0].Status')
system_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.SystemStatus.Details[0].Status')

jq -n --arg inst_status "$instance_status" \
      --arg sys_status "$system_status" \
      '{"instance_status":$inst_status,"system_status":$sys_status}'
```

Then in your TF:

```
data "external" "instance_status" {

  program = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_instance_status.sh"]

  query = {
    id = "i-08efdfdffb3"
  }
}

output "test" {
  value = data.external.instance_status.result
}
```

example output:

```
test = tomap({
  "instance_status" = "passed"
  "system_status" = "passed"
})
```

Comment: Getting this error , while excuting terraform plan : Error: failed to execute "bash": ./get_instance_status.sh: line 5: jq: command not found
./get_instance_status.sh: line 9: jq: command not found

Comment: @AnkitK You have to install `jq`.

Comment: It is working fine , if we pass instance id as i-08efdfdffb3  ,but can we pass instance id as QA-server-via-ami.id , as we are not knowing the instance id before terraform apply ?

Comment: @AnkitK Its custom data source. You can modify it to what suits your use-case. Your question was not specific on instance selection, so I showed instance-id which is the most commonly used.

Comment: Can you please share for reference ,of instance launched via ami named as 'QA-server-via-ami',whose id is not known before .

Comment: @AnkitK You can filter by `image-id` in [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html). So you can use that to find the instance-id (probably multiple instances), and then use the id to get instance status. I would suggest you trying to modify the script I provided. If you find difficulties, please make new question specific to the ami selection, with modified code and any error messages you have.

Comment: I have made a new question , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66885126/script-to-get-instance-status-1-2-or-2-2-of-instance-launched-via-ami-whose-inst?noredirect=1#comment118230502_66885126 .