# script to get Instance Status 1/2 or 2/2 of instance launched via AMI whose instance id is not known before in terraform using external data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Can i have script to get Instance Status check of 1/2 or 2/2 of instance launched via AMI whose instance id is not known before applying terraform apply in terraform using external data source .
[image]
Instance name launched via AMI  : QA-server-via-ami
Ami Name : QA-ami
[image]

```
    Error : 
    Error: failed to execute "bash":
    An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.Malformed) when calling the 
    DescribeInstanceStatus operation: Invalid id: "QA-server-via-ami.id"
    on main.tf line 94, in data "external" "instance_status":
    94: data "external" "instance_status"}
```

```
Main TF Code :
```

```
    resource "aws_ami_from_instance" "QA-ami" {
    name   = "QA-ami"
    source_instance_id = "i-00f4e52*****"
    }

    resource "aws_instance" "QA-server-via-ami" {
    ami = aws_ami_from_instance.QA-ami.id
    instance_type = "var.instance_type_QA"
    }

    data "external" "instance_status" {
    program = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_instance_status.sh"]
    query = {
    id = "QA-server-via-ami.id"
    }
    }
```

```
get_instance_status.sh :
```

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -e

    eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(QA-server-via-ami.id)"')"

    status=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} -- 
    output json --query 'InstanceStatuses[0]')

    instance_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.InstanceStatus.Details[0].Status')
    system_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.SystemStatus.Details[0].Status')

    jq -n --arg inst_status "$instance_status" \
      --arg sys_status "$system_status" \
      '{"instance_status":$inst_status,"system_status":$sys_status}'
```

Comment: remove the `"` around the `var.something`

Comment: Can you paste code as text block, not screanshots please.

Comment: @marcin Have pasted the text block .

Comment: And the `get_instance_status.sh`?

Comment: @marcin Have added now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you creating instance using:

```
resource "aws_instance" "QA-server-via-ami"
```

then to get its ID you can use:

```
aws_instance.QA-server-via-ami.id
```

So to pass it to your `external` data source:

```
data "external" "instance_status" {
    program = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_instance_status.sh"]
    query = {
      id = aws_instance.QA-server-via-ami.id
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to do any changes in get_instance_status.sh ?

Comment: @AnkitK Script should have `eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(.id)"')"`, not `eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(QA-server-via-ami.id)"')"`.

Comment: This is working fine for me now .Thanks a lot .

Comment: while running terraform apply ,once instance is launched ,it is showing initializing .after 5-10 min , again if we run terraform apply we get status passed or failed , Is there way we can get this output of 2/2 passed after sometime in terraform ?Our motive is to check the status passed or failed for instance launched via AMI .

Comment: @AnkitK You can add basic `sleep` in the script for 10 minutes or so. More elaborate solution requires some loop checking the status iteratively.